# DLNA PROTOCOL in Client Torrent

Tags: c++, streaming, bittorrent, dlna

Good afternoon,
I'm working in a project for KTorrent for an exam of my university in C++.
I have to add a DLNA plugin in KTorrent but I don't know how complex this is.
I want to know how can I implement this protocol and if somebody knows this one.
Thank you

Comment: What have you found in google?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out [libdlna](http://libdlna.geexbox.org/)